# Is there a way to `tar` extract without clobbering

Tags: tar

Is there a way to `tar` extract without clobbering?

I am installing 12.04 and want to restore my data from 10.10.  Anything 12.04 specific I would like to keep, that is I do not want the `tar`'d 10.10 version to be extracted.  If I do a general restore such files as .bashrc will be clobbered.  Is there a way to avoid this?

Edit: I would note that a booted 12.04 ISO disk image allows an upgrade from 10.10 (or whatever) and it offers to keep old data.  I tried this but it complained some applications might be left broken after the upgrade.  I decided to just reboot and do a clean install.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I have difficulty understanding what you want but if you made a tar file of your whole system I believe you made a very large tar file that has not a real purpose unless you completely restore the tar file. If you wanted to save your own documents you should have made a backup of those documents and nothing else.

After saying that tar has several nifty options ...

```
--keep-old-files
```

This will not overwrite existing files.

```
--keep-newer-files
```

This will keep all files that have a newer timestamp as is.

```
--no-overwrite-dir
```

This will leave the metadata of an existing directory as is.

[A manual for tar can be found here](http://www.petefreitag.com/tools/man-pages/tar.html).

But I would advice extracting the tar file on another medium and manually restore those files. It is the safest method.

Comment: Even with --keep-newer-files and --no-overwrite-dir, extracting an old full system backup onto a new system will leave your system in a goofed up state since many files that shouldn't be there will be extracted.  You should just open the archive in the gui with file-roller and extract the specific files you want to your home directory.

Comment: I agree as per my last line in my answer :)

Comment: @Rinzwind, you are right, my archive has a faulty design. Many exclusions and still not enough exclusions so it's a mess and dangerous to restore since it would be Maverick overwriting onto Precise. My next archive will be strictly inclusions. Your suggestion about manual restoration is a good one.

Answer (score 12):

From [tar(1)](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/tar.1):

```
 -k, --keep-old-files
       don't replace existing files when extracting
```

Seems clear to me. If files in the tarball are stored relatively to your old homedir:

```
tar xvkf backup.tar.gz -C ~
```

Comment: does this also work while compressing.

Comment: @nyxee It also works when trying to extract a compressed archive (e.g. `tar xvkzf backup.tar.gz -C ~`). I don't think it is recognized when you try to create a new archvie (`tar czf foo.tar.gz foo/`) if you are asking about that.